# malloc issue with "dynamic" array for copying a file

Tags: c, malloc

I'm making a simple program for copying files. Here's what I wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "extern.h"

#define fTrue 1
#define fFalse 0


FILE *fpSrc, *fpDest;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *temp;
    
    /* open files */
    if (argc != 3 || !fOpenFiles(argv))
        Usage();
    
    fseek(fpSrc, 0, SEEK_END);
    temp = (char *) malloc(sizeof(*temp) * ftell(fpSrc));
    fseek(fpSrc, 0, SEEK_SET);
    
    fread(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, fpSrc);
    fwrite(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, fpDest);
    
    if (fpSrc)
        fclose(fpSrc);
    
    if (fpDest)
        fclose(fpDest);
    
    free(temp);
    
    exit(0);
}


int fOpenFiles(char **psz)
{
    if (((fpSrc = fopen(*(++psz), "rb")) != NULL) &&
        (fpDest = fopen(*(++psz), "wb")) != NULL)
    {
        return fTrue;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error: cannot access %s\r\n", *psz);
        return fFalse;
    }
}


void Usage(void)
{
    (void)fprintf(stderr,
            "usage: %s [srcfile ...] [destfile ...]\n", getprogname());
        exit(1);
}
```

However, the following error appears at runtime

```
a.out(6566,0x105074580) malloc: \*\*\* error for object 0x547c264d42: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

I later used an if statement to check whether memory was allocated or not, but still it left me without a clue of what is happening.

Can you help me?

Comment: Given `char *temp;`, what exactly do you think `&temp` means?  See http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3

Comment: `sizeof(temp)` is the size of a pointer, not the amount of memory you allocated. Once you fix the crash you'll find your destination file is very small, either 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yeah, I'm trying to fix it. Unfortunately, there's no real way to determine the amount of memory allocated unless some OS specific macro is used. I have a weird feeling about this approach.

Comment: You know exactly how much memory there is because you allocated it. Assign `sizeof(*temp) * ftell(fpSrc)` to a variable and use it when you call malloc, fread, and fwrite. Since `sizeof(char)` is always 1 you can even just shorten it to `size_t fileSize = ftell(fpSrc);`.